# Java - How to keep it running without console window

Tags: java, parameters, console

I developed a java application that needs to be run with additional arguments.
Therefor I wrote a batch file that looks like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=data\ -cp SLV.jar;lib\comm.jar slv.SLV
```

When I start the batch file witht that content, it opens java and shows me the output of the "System.out.println" method. But When I close the console, which opened the batch file, the java programm gets closed too. Is there a way to close the console window but keep the Java apllication running? I tried to use a vbs. Script to run the batch invisibly with that content:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Then I used

```
wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"
```

But that doesn't work, so I wanted to see if there's a method directly implemented into the java runtime environment.

Comment: You mean a daemon/service? Does the application end after printing the message or is there some work to do in as for example in a server listening to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javaw.exe instead of java.exe. The console will never open.

Comment: That works 50%! If I open the batch file the console window opens, but I can close it, and the java application keeps running. But I can't execute any other commands after that, because it seems the batch file waits for the java programm to finish... But I suppose thats's a new Problem :/